# Need help to intercept Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE)communication through OWASP ZAP

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, zap

I have a requirement to security test a Mobile app which is standalone and connects to firmware through Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE).

Answer (score 0):

If it's web comms and you can direct it through ZAP then sure. If you're talking protocol level stuff then you're probably looking for something more like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/).

(Wireshark BT capture setup details are available [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth). You can learn about Wireshark's BLE display filter details [here](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/b/btle.html).)

Looks like this has been [answered elsewhere](https://groups.google.com/g/zaproxy-users/c/roj3oc735ng) as well.